# Query table from another ORACLE database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two different data base, one is `DEVORADB` which i use for development, and another one is `UATORADB` which tester use for testing. `UATORADB` have the most updated data which is not in development. I want to query tables from `UATORADB` database in `DEVORADB`. I was writing in `DEVORADB` in such a way but not getting the result:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME@UATDEVORADB.
```

Comment: its db_name.table_name

Comment: You need to connect to both databases (with unique db handles), and query each handle separately

Comment: @neokio: that'd only be true if the two tables are in completely separate instances of the db server, or the account in use doesn't have access to both tables. if they're within the same instance, then `select table.field from db.table` will work just fine.

Comment: Removed the `mysql` tag as the syntax is clearly for Oracle

Comment: Which database is Oracle and which one is MySQL?

Comment: If you're on Oracle, you'll need to [set up a dblink](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm).

Comment: For Oracle, **`CREATE DATABASE LINK`**.

Answer (score 20):

For Oracle,

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK ...
```

e.g.

With a database link created and tested, you can do a query (of the style you showed) to retrieve rows from a remote database.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF01205

**FOLLOWUP**

NOTE: In Oracle, the term "database" refers to the datafiles and logfiles associated with an Oracle "instance". To retrieve data from a second "database" means you need a second connection to the other database. Oracle provides a facility called a "database link". That allows a session(connection) to one database instance to connect to another database instance. (Without this facility, a client would need to create two separate connections, and would need to query the two databases separately.)

If this question is regarding querying from two separate "schemas" within the *same* database, as long as the user has sufficient privileges on objects in the second schema, the identifier can be qualified with the name of the schema, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM UATDEVORADB.TABLE_NAME
```

To access data on a separate database, a database link can be used...

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK UADEVORADB 
  CONNECT TO user 
  IDENTIFIED BY password
  USING 'uadevoradb' ;
```

(This will require an appropriate matching entry in the tnsnames.ora file on the Oracle server, or the oracle names server, or the connection details can be spelled out in place of a tnsnames.ora entry, something like:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK UADEVORADB
  CONNECT TO user IDENTIFIED BY password 
  USING '(DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=uadevorahost1)(PORT=1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=uadevoradb.domaindb)))'
```

If the "user" specified in the database link differs from the "owner" of the table on the remote system, and there's no synonym that references the table, the table identifier will need to be qualified with the owner...

```
SELECT * FROM OWNER.TABLE_NAME@UADEVORADB ;
```

Comment: how can i create link in TOAD

Comment: If you get an error in TOAD invoking the `CREATE DATABASE LINK` command, you don't have authority to create database links, in any SQL tool, and will likely need to have your DBA create the link, or grant you authority to create a link.

Comment: For this sample-code provided, I found that it is required for one more parentheses to be in USING clause: (DESCRIPTION=(...)) instead of DESCRIPTION=(...) If so - it works fine for me! Thanks for qualified answer!

Comment: @AlexeyPyankov: Thanks for pointing out the whole tnsnames entry should be enclosed in parens in the USING clause.  I've edited the answer to include that outer set of parens you recommended.  (I don't ever use a full tnsnames entry.  I always reference a TNSNAMES or LDAP entry by name.  If a hostname, a port or a service name needs to change, I can modify the tns entry, without having to change any db_link definitions.)

Comment: Just adding for reference that you can also use: `CREATE DATABASE LINK ADEVORADB CONNECT TO user IDENTIFIED BY password USING 'uadevorahost1:1521/uadevoradb.domaindb'`